# Powershell via batch file multiple statements

Tags: powershell, batch-file, psexec

This code is very close to being finished, however I cannot get the last statement (`psexec \\%PC% -i -d -s "\.exe`) that I wish to run, to run only if the device pings.

The aim is, **if** a device pings **then** write to host that it pings and run the psexec command **else** write to host that it hasn't been able to ping.

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
Clear-Host

set /p PC=PC no?:

FOR %%i IN (
    %PC%
) DO (
     PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "If (Test-Connection %%i -Count 1 -Quiet) { Write-Host "%%i - successfully pinged" -F Green } (psexec \\%PC% -i -d -s "\.exe that i wish to run") 
    else { Write-Host "%%i FAILED" -F Red}"
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like Spanglish or something.  `Clear-Host` isn't a command that `cmd` understands, and it'd be easier just to `ping`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    set /P "PC=PC no? "
) else (
    set "PC=%~1"
)

ping -n 1 %PC% | find /i "TTL=" >NUL 2>NUL && (
    powershell "Write-Host '%PC% passed' -f Green"
    psexec \\%PC% -i -d -s "\.exe that i wish to run"
) || (
    powershell "Write-Host '%PC% failed' -f Red"
)
```

For what it's worth, if you don't need the output of the command that `psexec` runs, I generally find `wmic process call create` to be faster than `psexec`.

```js
wmic /node:%PC% process call create "exe that you wish to run"
```

If you need to supply auth info, add the `/user:username` and `/password:password` switches before `process call create`.

---

There are several problems with your code above.  When executing a PowerShell command within a batch script, you can't break the line very easily.  You should also include your `psexec` command within the `if` code block, rather than after it as you have now.  You can separate commands with your braced code block with semicolons if needed.  And finally, you need to be careful mixing double quotes as part of the `powershell` command token with the double quotes within the command. It could be fixed so that powershell handles the conditional flow, but my solution above works just as well and is more readable I think.